# Pytest - Run the same test in slow mode and fast mode

Tags: python, pytest

PyTest is what I use to test my programs. One test uses a random generator, what is making the test statistical.

To achieve a specific degree of significance, the test must be run through a huge number of loops, which takes a long time. Most of the time, I am satisfied with a minimal number of iterations and the results obtained. The question is, how can I run the same test with multiple iterations based on the context of the test?

Here's an example of a small code that will assist me demonstrate my point:

```py
import pytest
import random
import statistics

def test_fast():
    delta_list = []
    for i in range(10):
         # The random process I employ is, of course, different,
         # and each iteration takes approximately a half-second.
        number = random.uniform(0, 1)
        expected_avg = 0.5
        delta = number - expected_avg 
        delta_list.append(delta)

    avg_delta = sum(delta_list) / len(delta_list)
    std_delta = (statistics.stdev(delta_list))
    assert avg_delta < 0.1
    assert std_delta < 0.15

@pytest.mark.slow
def test_fast():
    delta_list = []
    for i in range(100000):
        number = random.uniform(0, 1)
        expected_avg = 0.5
        delta = number - expected_avg 
        delta_list.append(delta)

    avg_delta = sum(delta_list) / len(delta_list)
    std_delta = (statistics.stdev(delta_list))
    assert avg_delta < 0.1
    assert std_delta < 0.15
```

The only variation between the tests, as you can see, is the number of loop iterations. I'd be delighted to configure the test so that if he runs in "fast mode", he does a few iterations and if he runs in "slow mode", he does a lot. There will be no code duplication.

How can I do that?

---

I run the rapid tests using `py.test` command and the slow tests with `py.test --runslow` command. This is done by setting the following configuration:

```
import pytest


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        "--runslow", action="store_true", default=False, help="run slow tests"
    )


def pytest_configure(config):
    config.addinivalue_line("markers", "slow: mark test as slow to run")


def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config, items):
    if config.getoption("--runslow"):
        # --runslow given in cli: do not skip slow tests
        return
    skip_slow = pytest.mark.skip(reason="need --runslow option to run")
    for item in items:
        if "slow" in item.keywords:
            item.add_marker(skip_slow)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can just factor out the non-trivial code into a utility function (whose name does *not* begin with `test_`), and take it from there:

```
def test_fast():
    run_repeatedly(10)

@pytest.mark.slow
def test_fast():
    run_repeatedly(100000)
```

And/or you can control the number of repetitions through configuration...